# Semantics vs Deduction

Tags: semantics, deduction

I know you can prove multiple ways, but I actually don't know what each means.

Is semantics where you provide a paragraph proof and use objects and deduction where you do subproofs/elimations/intros to get to the conclusion?

Comment: Hmm, well they're not conceptual opposites: the binaries would be something like semantic-syntactic and deductive-inductive

Answer (score 1):

Semantics is to do with meaning, and syntax is to do with form. Its quite possible to set up a deductive system and then formally prove something that is wrong; this because the semantics of the situation hasn't been taken into account.

To give a crude example one  could formally develop a theory of happiness by scoring peoples happiness out of ten; and then you can ask questions about the total amount of happiness, or its maximum and so on; but the semantics of this situation, when thought about, is *can* you measure a qualitive thing such as happiness quantitively? If this is even possible, how to take account of people lying, or not being aware of the true state of their happiness: it isn't for nothing that 'know thyself' was inscribed in the forecourt of the Temple of Apollo at Delphi. All these are common objection to theory of Utilitarianism as developed by Bentham.

Comment: Not really my question. but I figure my initial tought was right. I know they overlap in some respects.
BUT does providing a semantic or a deduction appeal to sound or completeness'

Comment: Soundness/completeness are properties (or not) of formal deductive systems; when logicians build or investigate such systems they try to show that these properties hold as they are so desirable; these formal systems are built in two parts - syntax and semantics; these are only very loosely related to what you are asking in your question.

Comment: Because they are built in two parts there are two forms of deduction - syntactical and semantic; and they need to correspond; a logical system would be of little use if I could syntactically prove a theorem, but when I prove it semantically, I either can't do it, or its shown its false. The two directions of this correspondence are called completeness and soundness.

Comment: Only one comment : without a "semantics" appropriate for the language of the deductive system, how to say that something we have formally proven "is wrong" ? Without semantics we can only speak of "syntactical" properties like *consistency*.

Comment: @Allegranza: I'm not specifically talking about the syntax-semantics paradigm in Modern Logic; that doesn't seem to be the concern of the OP; judging by how he put his question. Semantics does have a range of meanings other than the purely mathematical-logic one.